# How can I make a user-friendly account approval for admins?

Tags: emails, users

Right now on my Drupal site I have everything set to send an email to the administrator once an account is created.

The administrator receives a link that says a new account is created, and there's a link to the user's profile in the email.

Is there any way for there to be a little option on the user's profile page that just says 'approve user' (that only the admin can see), or for an admin to get a link submitted to him through the email that he can click to automatically approve a user?

I'd rather admins not have to dig through the backend, look up a user, and then edit the user and approve the account manually.  Is this possible? The most preferable would be the the administrator gets an 'approval link' in the email, so he can just click 'approve' from his email, and assuming he's logged in on the site, it automatically approves the new user account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two modules that you can take a look into

[Admin Users](https://drupal.org/project/admin_users)

> This module helps to administrate all registered users. You can sort
>   out users according to their status (active or blocked), the number of
>   published nodes, the number of comments, the last visit or the period
>   of registration. You can also change the role of any user, block or
>   delete many users with one click just ticking them in the table.

[Multi-admin pending approval notifications (MAPAN)](https://drupal.org/project/mapan)

> **Problem**
>
> The current behavior in Drupal core when a new user registers
>   requesting approval sends mail only to the site's contact address.
>   Thus only one person is notified even though there may be several
>   administrators/moderators.
>
> **Solution**
>
> This module improves this basic behavior by notifying all users that
>   have the 'administer users' permission by default.
>   Administrators/moderators get a setting to disable these notifications
>   in their user profile form. A link is also appended to each of these
>   notifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is another module called [User registration notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_register_notify) which states

- Allows admin notifications to roles or custom e-mail address
- Allows changing the 'from' address
- Allows adding custom 'reply-to' address
- Settings can change all core account setting e-mail templates
- Allows you to send emails on user create/update/delete to your delegated users
- Allows selection of e-mail message types that will be altered
- Allow customization of Core hidden Admin (pending admin approval) e-mail

but in hindsight it offers nothing towards what sound like the crux of the OP, namely that approval can be triggered by just 'clicking a link in an email'